# Can I "namespace" an ajax POST request that uses FormData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1406664) explaining how to use a `FormData` object to upload a file over ajax. I'm wondering if it's possible to rearrange the data structure that's sent over in the POST request.

My backend is in rails, and the controller expects the data like this:

```
xmlFile: {
  some_property: 1,
  attachment: [the file]
}
```

However, if I use a solution similar to the one from the above link, something like

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('some_property', id);
data.append('source', file);
```

(where `file` is a `File` object), and then submit that with `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
  mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
});
```

the form submits, but the data isn't namespaced under `xmlFile`. If I try to do something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: {xmlFile: data},
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
  mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
});
```

it doesn't work. The request data just shows [object Object].

Comment: First `xmlFile = data;` then `data: xmlFile`

Comment: @AmitJoki Hmm I don't understand, could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know if it works, but what I meant to say is assign a variable xmlFile to data beforehand and then in $.ajax, you can pass xmlFile for data

Comment: Doesn't seem to work